# Remove the first character of the first index of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

**Question:**  How do you remove the first character of the first index of an array.

```
var arr = ['/a','b','c','r'];
```

I would like to output

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','r'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code

```
arr[0] = arr[0].substr(1);
```